# searching an html document for a certain part and replacing

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an HTML page, and from javascript, I would like to use regex to find a certain item within that HTML page and replace it with a different string...

specifically, this item is within a script section in the body of the HTML document

I am using hls for streaming video..

and in the body, there is a script section that includes the line

```
hls.loadSource('http://streaming.com/stream.m3u8');
```

I would like to use regex to find the string of that m3u8 file link, so basically, any string that fits the pattern `http://(anything).m3u8` and then replace it with a new string.

does anyone know of a good method to use regex to search an entire html  document for a string that fits that regex, and then how i could replace just that one string in the document?

Comment: What language are you using your HTML with?

Comment: I am using node.js and javascript to create a webserver, and am serving up HTML pages, I want to change an HTML document from my main node.js server javascript file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for could be `^'http://.*\.m3u8'$` .
Now you can use this in almost any language and replace it.

If your language is Javascript,

```
str.replace(new RegExp("^'http://.*\.m3u8'$"), "myURL");
```

will do. You need to read the complete content of your HTML into `str`.

Comment: "dot" `(.)` means "match any single character here", but you want to match the actual _period_ as part of the whole `.m3u8` file extension -- so escape the dot: `http://.*\.m3u8`

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript, you can use a Regex to replace the entire HTML using the  `document.body.innerHTML` property:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( new RegExp("^'http://.*\.m3u8'$"), "foo");
```